# Simple Path and Simple Cycle in Graph DataStructure

Tags: data-structures, graph, digraphs

I am unable to understand that does simple path in graph always contains first and last vertices as same?Can simple path be simple cycle ? Can simple cycle be simple path in graph data structure?Please help me out!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A path is a path(sequences of vertices where each vertex is adjacent to vertex next to it), simple path does not repeat vertices. So, a simple path is not a cycle. simple path does not contain same vertex as ending and starting.

A simple cycle is a cycle in which only(no other vertices are repeated) the starting and ending vertices are repeated. so a simple cycle is a path but not simple path.

Comment: can you please provide some references to this?